# miss css file/module not found problems in react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, less

I have been experiencing this issue for a long time. I have a lot of projects with pure html/css/js. in my css file there are a lot of codes in which i have written to get an image from directories. but the problem is that the image does not exist. For example:

```
.bg-img {
    background-image: url("./../img/foo.jpg");
}
```

in this example `foo.jpg` does not exist in this directory. but i did not use `.bg-img` class in html. So this did not caused any problem as i was not using it. But while converting this to React i noticed that React has stricter rules and caused problems with compiling.
So is there any way that i can make react neglect/miss these problems and continue compiling.

By the way, the reason why i have these unnecessary css codes causing problems is that i have copy pasted from another template's css codes and did not removed them as there was a bunch more of them.

So Please don't respond me like: "remove unnecessary css codes"

Thank you for your response :).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using strict mode in React? https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html Another thing - you should probably simply remove the styles you don't use :) it will help with your warnings/errors as well ;)

Comment: no i am not using strict mode. i have no idea of what it is. I told you that i cannot remove these styles bro. There are too much of them. These css codes are from another projects's csses. So i cannot remove them. If i could i wouldn't post them to StackOverflow.